# Log queries not using indexes without bunch of system and show tables stuff

Tags: mysql

I do want to enable [log-queries-not-using-indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-queries-not-using-indexes) of MySQL 5.0 but I do not want to have all the system queries there like `SHOW TABLES, GRANTS` and etc... which are indeed not using indexes.

How can I get a sanitized output or is there a different configuration available?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @zeflex I don't remember doing so, as I would have answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but setting `--log-slow-admin-statements` to `false` might help?
It certainly would be nice if it did.

If it doesn't work, you may want to try your luck with Oracle to implement it. :-(